# z-index not working out of the container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap and i'm trying to display an element out of the container.

[html]

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

[css]

```
.element{
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
z-index:999;}
```

My problem is: why the block element still hidden by the container. what's wrong about my 'z-index' ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, but the `container` won't show unless there is something inside it, and an absolute position div is taken outside the normal DOM flow so the container will collapse.

```
<div class="container bg-danger">
    &nbsp;
    <div class="element bg-info">element</div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/gqMwCQ3m01

Comment: my container is not empty.
i put a carousel on a container and  i want to display the indicators out of the carousel(out of the container)
container's border always hide them. i just want to know what could be the problem !

Comment: i delete proprty 'position' from other block of carousel. indicators showed out of the container.
i fix it but i still i don't undrestand the problem